# Kdenlive v21 crashes during render

Tags: crash, kdenlive

I'm using Kdenlive v21.04.3 on Ubuntu 20.04.2. When I try to render, either the PC freezes, the PC reboots on its own, or Kdenlive stays up in various states. Occasionally Kdenlive provides an error log. Here is the output from the last failure:

```
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 3.2.1+1-b5c86a64bbbe x265 [info]: build info [Linux][GCC 9.3.0][64 bit] 8bit+10bit+12bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2 
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-4 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 4 threads x265 [info]: Slices : 1 
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features : 2 / wpp(17 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8 
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra 
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge : hex / 57 / 2 / 2 x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias: 25 / 250 / 40 / 5.00 
hx265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt : 15 / 4 / 0 
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb : 1 / 1 / 0 
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit cu / depth : 2 / on / on 
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree : 2 / 1.0 / 32 / 1 
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress : CRF-23.0 / 0.60 
x265 [info]: tools: rd=2 psy-rd=2.00 early-skip rskip signhide tmvp fast-intra
x265 [info]: tools: strong-intra-smoothing lslices=6 deblock sao
[mp4 @ 0x7f5b98000f40] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead. 
[mp4 @ 0x7f5b98000f40] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
```

I've tried lots of video output configurations, rendering to different folder locations, rendering short unedited clips. I was running with an onboard SSD hard drive (its built into the Gigabyte motherboard), and suspected it was a problem. So I just installed a new internal SSD HD, with a new copy of Ubuntu and Kdenlive, but it didn't help.
On the old HD, I rolled back to Kdenlive v19 (with ubuntu 20.o4) but no joy.
I use to render OK using an older version of Ubuntu and Kdenlive v19.
I'm open to any suggestions. I'm at my wits end.

---

Here is another kdenlive report from another crash:

```
Rendering ... video/1st3clips2.mp4 crashed

no more csLADSPA plugins
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f33102219c0] Value 1.000000 for parameter 'seekable' out of range [-1 - 0]
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f3310240840] Value 1.000000 for parameter 'seekable' out of range [-1 - 0]
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f331047ed80] Value 1.000000 for parameter 'seekable' out of range [-1 - 0]
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f3310847440] Value 1.000000 for parameter 'seekable' out of range [-1 - 0]
[mp4 @ 0x7f3310000f40] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead. [mp4 @ 0x7f3310000f40] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
```

On the latter crash, kdenlive kept running and Ubuntu generated its own crash report that included: "melt crashed with SIGSEGV". I haven't yet figured out how to copy the text from Ubuntu crash reports. Sorry about the changing fonts here. Its not something I did intentionally.

Here is another crash report.

```
Rendering of /home/lekcin/Videos/Render 2.mp4 crashed

[mp4 @ 0x7f3804000f40] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead. [mp4 @ 0x7f3804000f40] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
```

Ubuntu also generated a crash report on this render crash.
The Title is: `melt crashed with SIGSEGV inx264_8_trellis_coefn()`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I saw that the crash was due to a high RAM and SWAP usage. It stop crashing when I put more RAM and/or increasing the size of SWAP partition. You can see if it is your case too by running htop or other tool that shows the memory and SWAP usage while rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled onto something that works in both Kdenlive and Shotcut.

In Kdenlive:
In the Rendering options, I chose: /Presets/Hardware Accelerated (experimental)/VAAPI Intel H264.
I chose the VAAP Intel H264 option simply because I have an Intel CPU.

In Shotcut:
In the Render options I selected, Use Hardware Encoder.

Before configuring for "Hardware," the CPU threads would run around 100% during the renders, in either Kdenlive or Shotcut.
With the Hardware options selected, the CPU threads are running at a reasonable average of about 60%.
About 9 out of 10 of my renders are successful now.

Answer (score 0):

when I encountered this issue, I disabled multithreading and the render stopped crashing.